# How can I monitor onkeyup/down events with special keys (returning zero keyCode)?

Tags: javascript, onkeydown, onkeyup

I use `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` events to implement a 8-bit computer emulator in javascript. I badly need these events (and not keypress!) as I need to emulate the keyboard matrix state of the emulated computer, so I have to know when a key is pressed and released.

That works fine, but sometimes `event.keyCode` returns with **zero**. I have no idea what to do with this situation. This is also the situation when a "special" key is pressed like non-English character on a Hungarian keyboard layout (as I am Hungarian). I still need that keys to be decoded though, not with the same meaning as it would mean in a generic application. The scenario is to emulate the key events of the emulated computer by key "position" on the keyboard, not the actual meaning.

Is there a way at least to tell which key is pressed when I got keyCode 0 from the event? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's keyup event.
If I understand your question right you want to be able to retrieve the keycode of the pressed key.
I use a function like this to check for the enter key.
For a full list of key codes, refer to [this page](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).

```
$(window).keyup(function(e){
    if(e.which === 13)
        // enter key pressed
});
```

Comment: Well yes, but this works perfectly for me, with "regular keys" like Enter, English letters etc, without Jquery too (using simple events). The problem is with special keys like Hungarian characters where I got zero as keyCode. But good idea, I will check Jquery out what it will does with those keys ...